# pip install gspread installs to python not py

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

running windows 10 here.

when I install gspread in cmd with `pip install gspread` it's all fine

but in cmd when I type `test.py` with just 1 line in it: `import gspread`, cmd returns a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'

in cmd, when I type `python test.py` it'll be fine.

I'm learning that it's because my windows default when I run a .py file runs py.exe, not python.exe

Does anyone know how I can install gspread such that when I run `py test.py` it'll have the module installed?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have more than one version of python installed. I would run in `cmd`

```
python --version
```

and

```
python -V
```

(notice capitol V) to see what versions those reference

And then run a script as `test.py` with just

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

This will help you see what versions you have running and which the `python test.py` is calling

It will allow you to either set up an alias to your preferred python version with the package already installed or pip install into the current one explicitly.
The caveat being I work in Mac environment and would use a more linux way of setting things up that on a pc. But you can expressly set a path to the version of python you wish to use without prefixing `python` like this:

[how to run python script without `python`](https://superuser.com/questions/828737/run-python-scripts-without-explicitly-invoking-python)